# Can't put margin on image

Tags: css, html

I am doing a website in wordpress. And under the navigation I have container(id="cover_photo") for image(id="cover_photo_image).I center it with margin but I want to move it down, and center it in the container, but the container follow if I put margin on it.

HTML

```
    <div id="cover_photo">
        <p id="cover_photo_image">
        </p>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
#cover_photo {
    width: 100%;
    height: 278px;
    background-color: #6b0c0b;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 3px 0px #888, 0px 0px -3px 0px #888;
}

p#cover_photo_image {
    width: 821px;
    height: 172px;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 6px;
    background-image: url(images/cover_photo.png);
}
```

Comment: Is there a good reason why you use a `p`aragraph instead of an `img`age element? Beside that, try to stick all margins into a single rule: `margin: 6px auto 0;`

Comment: Do you want to vertically center the image?

Comment: Can you give us a screenshot? What are you trying to achieve with the centering, both vertical and horizontal centering?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plopped your code into a fiddle and saw what you mean. The problem is that you haven't set positioning for `#cover_photo` or `#cover_photo_image`. The outer element needs to be relative, the inner needs to be an absolute.

```
#cover_photo {
position: relative;
}

p#cover_photo_image {
position: absolute;
}​
```

I changed the sizes so it would fit into the preview, and if you try adjusting the margin values it should move around and not move the `#cover_photo` container.

http://jsfiddle.net/ESCNm/

Just in case you're are looking to automatically vertically and horizontally align an element within an element, there are a LOT more methods that manual positioning. Manual positioning is such a hassle, and I try to avoid absolutes whenever possible.

Here an article about it: http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/vertical-centering/

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It work but I agree with absolutes, they make everything confusing in the end ;)

Answer (score 0):

About vertical and horizontal centering.

You can use Flex.

Please add the following code

```
#cover_photo {
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
   align-items:center;
}

p#cover_photo_image {
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-image: url(https://cdn.sstatic.net/Img/teams/teams-illo-free- 
  sidebar-promo.svg?v=47faa659a05e);
  background-size: contain;
  background-position: center;
}
```

This should be the effect you want.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jl99e.png)